# kohana measure database execution time

Tags: php, database, profiling, kohana

Is there any way in Kohana framework to measure (and display somehow) the analysis of database query execution? In symfony 1.x there was a `debug toolbar` (see image: http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/0/0c/Symfony-06e_NB68symfony_es.jpg), in symfony2 there is a profiler tool. I couldn't find anything like this neither in Kohana standard edition nor in web resources.

I'm using particularly kohana 3.2, but I guess it could be very similar in all 3.x versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in Kohana [profiler](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/profiling). I always use it like this in my template view:

```
<?php if (Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION) : ?>
    <div class="footer">
        <?php echo View::factory('profiler/stats') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

To show database connections you need to enable profiling in the config/database.php (this is where your DB settings are stored). You can explicitly write TRUE or check the `Kohana::$environment` variable:

```
return array
(
    'default' => array(
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            'dsn'        => '',
            'username'   => 'yyy',
            'password'   => 'zzz',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
                'identifier'   => '',
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => Kohana::$environment === Kohana::PRODUCTION,
        'profiling'    => Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION,
    ),
```

You also need to enable profiling in the bootstrap. This is what I usually do:

```
if (Arr::get($_SERVER, 'SERVER_NAME') !== 'localhost') // OR your testing URL
{
    Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT);
    $server_name = 'productions_url';
}
else
{
    Kohana::$environment = Kohana::DEVELOPMENT;
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $server_name = 'testing_url';
}

Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url' => $server_name,
    'index_file' => FALSE,
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'cache_dir' => APPPATH . 'cache',
    'errors' => TRUE,
    'profile' => Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION,
    'caching' => Kohana::$environment === Kohana::PRODUCTION,
));
```

Comment: does it display database connections automatically or do I have to code something more than this view?